# Make zsh alt-f behave like emacs alt-f

Tags: zsh

In emacs, `M-f` moves the caret to the end of the next word. In zsh, `M-f` (or rather `alt-f`) moves the caret to the beginning of the next word.

For a more consistent experience, I'd like to have zsh `alt-f` mirror emacs behavior.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
bindkey '\ef' emacs-forward-word
```

See:

```
zle -la | grep word
```

to list the widgets that contain the word `word`.

```
info --index-search=emacs-forward-word zsh
```

to get the documentation on a given widget.

Comment: Mapping `\M-f` to `emacs-forward-word` did not work for me. Searching with `bindkey | grep forward-word` showed that the correct mapping on my system was to `^[f` and `^[F`.

Comment: @EricHuang, yes sorry, `\M-f` is `f` with the eighth bit set. Some terminals send that upon Alt-F but they are getting rare in those utf8 days. I'll amend the answer as `\ef` is likely to be useful to more people.

Comment: This is close but not the same. `bash`/`libreadline`/`emacs` will move the cursor to `c` in `a-b-c`. But `emacs-backward-word` moves the cursor to `a`. What is the correct `zsh` option which actually provides `emacs`-like behavior?